# Handling after commit instances in sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, events, sqlalchemy, signals, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a flask app using sqlachemy but I was wondering whether there is a more efficient way (like in django with the signals) to handle after commit rather than doing something like that (it seems to me like it is an overkill):

```
@listens_for(db.session, "before_flush")
def before_flush(session: Session, *args) -> None:
    """
     Handling pre flushing ops

     Parameters:
     ---------------------------
             session: Session
             * args

     Returns:
     ---------------------------
             None
    """

    session.info['flushed'] = list()

    for target in session.new:
        if hasattr(target, 'before_flush'):
            target.before_flush(session, 'new')
            session.info['flushed'].append((target, True))


@listens_for(db.session, "after_commit")
def after_commit(session: Session, *args) -> None:
    """
    Handling post commit ops

    Parameters:
    ---------------------------
            session: Session
            * args
    Returns:
    ---------------------------
            None
    """

    for target in session.info['flushed']:
        instance, created = target

        if hasattr(instance, 'after_commit'):
            instance.after_commit(session, created)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to pre-commit and post-commit for different db hits. Meanwhile, the primary use is to send emails (once the user activate its account, etc...).